# Cómo respetar los saltos de linea de cada párrafo que almaceno en una base de datos mysql en ionic?

Tags: html5, ionic, react-native

Hola tengo una duda con respecto al visualizar un parrafo en ionic que mando llamar desde una base de datos(mysql). Lo que pretendo hacer es que respete los espacios de cada párrafo lo cual no hace en la imagen, sino que todo lo junta como un párrafo. Alguna sugerencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hago es desde la base de datos generar parrafos y separarlos por 
 para que haga saltos de linea, pero al visualizarlo en la vista omite el 
 y lo imprime tal cual esto lo hago dentro de la etiquta

```
<p>{{noticia.descripcin}}<p/>
```

Comment: Hola cuando dices salto de linea te refieres a `<br>` ?

Comment: Si exactamente a eso. Ya que desde mi proyecto laravel cuento con un editor el cual se redacta una noticia, la cual contiene varios parrafos separados por  saltos de linea o espaciados, y al visualizar esta nota, en mi app movil se ve todo junto, o sea no respeta la separación entre parrafos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para utilizar Codigo HTML Guardado en la base de datos  utiliza el siguiente codigo

```
 <div [innerHTML]="Nombredelavariable"></div>
```

Espero que te sirva  un saludo

Comment: me marca error cuando la cadena contiene estos signos <>